# Trying to Update Case When Then, based on matching IDs in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to updated IDs in a table named Price, based on matches of IDs in a table named CW.  Here is the SQL that I'm testing.

```
UPDATE Price
SET    ISN = (case when CW.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN CW.id_number else ISN end),
       SED = (case when CW.id_cd = 'SED' THEN CW.id_number else SED end),
       CSP = (case when CW.id_cd = 'CSP' THEN CW.id_number else CSP end)
FROM   CW
WHERE  Price.ID_GLOBAL = CW.asset_id
```

Here is a screen shot of the two schemas.  So, now the values in the yellow cells are missing IDs, but I'm trying to get them filled in with the values I'm showing here.

[image]

The weird thing is that most of the IDs in the Price table are updated fine, based on the same IDs in the CW table, but not all IDs are being updated.  After doing the above update, when I run the SQL below, I get a bunch of records returned, but I would expect no records at all because all CSP (IDs) should have been updated in the Price table.

```
Select *
From Price
INNER JOIN CW
ON Price.id_global = CW.asset_id
Where Price.CSP IS NUll
AND CW.id_cd = 'CSP'
```

Comment: Do you have any trailing spaces in either Price.id_global or CW.asset_id that would cause them not to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have multiple rows in `CW` for each `ID_GLOBAL`.  The problem is that only one matching row gets used.  The solution is either a series of `LEFT JOIN`s or pre-aggregation:

```
UPDATE Price
    SET ISN = COALESCE(cw.isn, price.isn),
        SED = COALESCE(cw.sed, price.sed),
        CSP = COALESCE(cw.csp, price.csp)
FROM (SELECT asset_id,
             MAX(case when CW.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN CW.id_number END) as ISN,
             MAX(case when CW.id_cd = 'SED' THEN CW.id_number END) as SED,
             MAX(case when CW.id_cd = 'CSP' THEN CW.id_number END) as CSP
      FROM CW
      GROUP BY asset_id
     ) cw
WHERE Price.ID_GLOBAL = CW.asset_id;
```

Note:  This assumes that the new values are not ever `NULL`.  If that is a possibility, the assignment logic needs to take that into account.  I am guessing that complication is unnecessary.

EDIT:

Do this in three steps.  For `'ISN'`:

```
UPDATE Price
    SET ISN = cw.isn
FROM CW
WHERE Price.ID_GLOBAL = CW.asset_id AND
      CW.id_cd = 'ISN';
```

I am guessing the `COALESCE()` is not necessary.

Comment: It sounds right, but I'm getting this error. FROM clause in UPDATE and DELETE statements cannot contain subquery sources or joins.
Can I do this in 3 separate steps.  This is a weird version of SQL Server; it's an Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  Some functionality of SQL Server works, and some things are stripped out.  Thanks.

Comment: I did this: SET ISN = cw.id_number
Then the updated logic works perfect.  What was wrong with my initial attempt?  Why did the Case...When...Then...not work?  Is it because the 'asset_id' and 'ID_GLOBAL' are not unique?  Is that it?

Comment: Thanks for the assist here!!